# Binding to count on observable collection of subclass

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I do have a WPF binding question here.

Following Setup:

I do have a class (ActionService) having a name and a ObservableCollection of subitems (also a class named Step). A Step has a flag that shows if the Step is allready done (IsDone).

I bind a form to the ActionService and display all kind of things.

Everything works as aspected and i have just the essential parts in my snippet.

Now I need one more thing that i can not get work. I want the ActionService to know by binding how many of its Steps are open (IsDone == false). I you open a childform with one of the steps and change the IsDone-State, the mother form should get the new count on the fly.

And I'm to dumb to get a correct solution on the way ;-)

Thanks for your help or a best practise.

```html
public class ActionService : BaseObject
{
 public ActionService()
 {
 }

 private String name;
 public String Name
 {
  get { return this.name; }
  set
  {
   this.name = value;
   raisePropertyChanged("Name");
  }
 }

 public ObservableCollection<Step> actionsteps;
 public ObservableCollection<Step> ActionSteps
 {
  get { return this.actionsteps; }
  set
  {
   this.actionsteps = value;
   raisePropertyChanged("ActionSteps");
  }
 }
 
}

public class Step : BaseObject
{
 public Step()
 {
 }
 
 private String description;
 public String Description
 {
  get { return this.description; }
  set
  {
   this.description = value;
   raisePropertyChanged("Description");
  }
 }
 
 private Boolean isdone;
 public Boolean IsDone
 {
  get { return this.isdone; }
  set
  {
   this.isdone = value;
   raisePropertyChanged("IsDone");
  }
 }
}

public class BaseObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 
 protected void raisePropertyChanged(String parPropertyName)
 {
  if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
  {
   this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(parPropertyName));
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new property in your `ActionService` class:

```
public bool IsDone
    {
        get 
        {
            return ActionSteps.Count(x => x.IsDone) == ActionSteps.Count;
        }
    }
```

*If the count of Steps in the ActionSteps list where the IsDone property is true is equal to the number of Steps in the ActionSteps list, then return true, else, return false.*

To subscribe to the Steps property changed event, when you add an item to the collection, you simply need to subscribe to the **PropertyChanged** event:

```
//Create the item and subscribe to propertychanged.
Step item = new Step();
item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;

//Add the item to the list.
ActionSteps.Add(item);
```

And your method will look like this:

```
void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsDone")
            raisePropertyChanged("IsDone");
    }
```

Comment: and listen to property changes for each action step IsDone Property, when it changes, re get IsDone

Comment: @Muds: how do i listen to a property change event of a class in my observable collection? thats my missing link ;-)

Comment: well you can first listen to collection changed event in your collection, then if a new item is added do a += event handler on newly added item's property changed, if an item is removed, remove that event.. makes sense ?

Comment: @Muds: sorry - i dont get it. could you provide a short code snippet. I'd be more than thankful. Mike

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain how to call the property changed event when the **IsDone** property changes on any item in the collection. Let me know if if that's clear.

Comment: thanks mikey ! also make sure to listen to collection changed

Comment: thanks guys! still need to figure out some relevant points for me, but my inital question has been answered! helped a lot!!